# In ConcurrentHashMap, why don't use ReentrantReadWriteLock in place of ReentrantLock on segment

Tags: java, performance, java.util.concurrent

Since the **ConcurrentHashMap** can't 100% secure consistency on the write operation (i.e. **size()**), using the **ReentrantReadWriteLock**(or it's derived class by customizing) instead can improve the performance, right?

Comment: Why don't you write a benchmark and see?  (Hint: getting a good coverage of typical use-cases is going to be tricky ...)

Comment: yes, I know, but I want to know the generic scenario of ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: There is no such thing a generic scenario.  The performance impact of what you are proposing will *vary* depend on how the map is used.

Answer (score 2):

Performance improvement will depend upon kind of operation you want to do. If you want to read more then yes otherwise while a thread is writing [i.e has taken write lock] , no other thread can take read or write lock so performance gain wont be there.